# JQuery Plugin - Binding an event to a dynamic element

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm building my first JQuery plugin and learning the standards for the plugins. I'm creating dynamic elements in my plugin like this -

```
var control = $("<table><tr><td><div>Test Control</div></td><td><img src='' /></td></tr></table>")
//Add the control to the document
```

Now how can I register the click event of the div inside the table?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run before you can walk – you should be comfortable with the basics of jQuery before writing a plugin. Here's a good place to start: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials.

Comment: I'm working with JQuery for the past two years. Just got mixed up with the documentation for writing a plugin where binding the events was mentioned. I fixed it before I got the answer here :). Got confused with .bind().

Comment: Ok. Perhaps you were focusing too much on the documentation, as after two years you should instinctively know exactly what the jQuery object you instantiate represents and how to navigate it – the fact that you're writing a plugin is not relevant to your question. Good luck with the plugin, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like so (I added a class and replaced it with anchor, just so it's more specific and semantic):

```
var control = $('<table><tr><td><a class="test" href="#">Test Control</a></td><td><img src='' /></td></tr></table>');
// Add control to document
control.find('a.test').click(function(e)
{
   // Do whatever...
   e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default behavior of the anchor
});
```

Comment: Okie it is like a part of long table. I've edited the question.